# how improve order by in search query? PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, sql-order-by, psql, tsvector

i need some help.
site has 2 sort types: by relevancy and date.
Sometimes happends that issues with most high score are to old, and the newest has small score.
So needed some common  query based on 2 marks.

Relecancy query looks like `'ORDER BY' ts_rank(EXTENDED_INDEX, custom_tsquery('english', 'test', 0))'`

and second one just `'ORDER BY table.date'`

Are any ideas how improve search? Maybe some second ts_rank by date?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the question it's unclear what dataset you are using as an example, but you can basically use [`ORDER BY rank DESC,date DESC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html) in your query, so you will have most "recent" and highly "ranked" at the top of your result set.

```
WITH t(id,t,d) AS ( VALUES
  (1,to_tsvector('english','one'),'2016-03-18'::DATE),
  (2,to_tsvector('english','two words'),'2016-03-17'::DATE),
  (3,to_tsvector('english','three words we are looking for'),'2016-03-16'::DATE),
  (4,to_tsvector('english','four words goes here'),'2016-03-15'::DATE)
)
SELECT
  id,
  ts_rank(t,q) AS rank,
  d
FROM t,to_tsquery('english','three | words') AS q
ORDER BY rank DESC NULLS LAST,d DESC;
```

Result :

```
 id |   rank    |     d      
----+-----------+------------
  3 | 0.0607927 | 2016-03-16
  2 | 0.0303964 | 2016-03-17
  4 | 0.0303964 | 2016-03-15
  1 |         0 | 2016-03-18
(4 rows)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but we need bigger influence of date, so decided to choose such variant

**ORDER BY ts_rank()^2/abs(date_difference+0.5)**
where date_difference - days count between today and post date
(maybe it will help somebody)